# Jquery DataTable column Sum

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I just refer [this link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) to get idea how to get the column total in jquery data tables. But I have done half of my project. I do not have any definition in html page. all include in Jquery side.

In HTML

```
 <table id="tblCollection" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        </table>
```

Defined data table like below in Jquery.

```
   tblColectionData = $("#tblCollection").DataTable({
        "ordering": true,
        columns: [
            { title: 'OrderId', data: 'OrderId' },
            { title: 'Ordered Date', data: 'OrderPlaceDateTime' },
            { title: 'Customer Name', data: 'CustomerName' },
            { title: 'Restaurant Name', data: 'RestaurantName' },
            { title: 'Order Total', data: 'OrderTotalAmount' }
        ],
    });
```

How to add **footerCallback** part in my case? The example in web link is defined the total in *tfoot*. In my case it is not. How to do this?

> EDIT 1

Fill data to datatable

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/getOrderData",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(reqJson),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (response) {
        tblColectionData.clear().draw();
        tblColectionData.rows.add(response).draw();
    },
    error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Err');
    }
});
```

Comment: in the example ist the footerCallback function, that generates that total sum. You have to write your own code for to do that

Comment: That is what I asking how to do it? How to embed footer to jquery datatable section in above code?

Comment: "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        // your code !!!
  }, thats between your plugin init "DataTable({ HERE CALLBACK })"

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to get sum of any field do this:

Add the 'footerCallback' function into DataTable() as follow and get 'data' parameter.

Example:

```
$("#example_table").DataTable({
     "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {                
                //Get data here 
                console.log(data);
                //Do whatever you want. Example:
                var totalAmount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    totalAmount += parseFloat(data[i][4]);
                }
                console.log(totalAmount);
       }
})
```

Be careful about the position of data index you want.

Enjoy it!!!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to sum the "order total column” (column number 4), you could do it as in the example provided by the Datatables documentation:

```
$('#tblCollection').dataTable( {
    ordering: true,
    columns: [
        { title: 'OrderId', data: 'OrderId' },
        { title: 'Ordered Date', data: 'OrderPlaceDateTime' },
        { title: 'Customer Name', data: 'CustomerName' },
        { title: 'Restaurant Name', data: 'RestaurantName' },
        { title: 'Order Total', data: 'OrderTotalAmount' }
    ],
    footerCallback: function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api();
        $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
            api.column(4).data().reduce(function ( a, b ) {
                return a + b;
            }, 0)
        );
    }
});
```

And then the table needs the `tfoot` for the callback to be executed:

```
<table id="tblCollection" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Order id</th>
            <th>Order date</th>
            <th>Customer name</th>
            <th>Restaurant name</th>
            <th>Order total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         ... your data here ...
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

> Note that if the table does not have a tfoot element, this callback will not be fired.

You can find more about `footerCallback` [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation muecas. But where I stuck is, I fill data to datatable using AJAX call. (EDIT 1 section). You can see I simply bind data values using it. But in given example, how to do it?

Comment: @weeraa why don't you use the Datatables implementation for ajax instead of your own implementation?

Answer (score 0):

`footerCallback` data will display an array looping over the element and summing will give you the total

```
$("#datatable_id").DataTable({
     "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {                
                var totalQTY = 0;
                data.forEach(element => {
                     console.log('element    ===> ', element.qty)
                     totalQTY += parseFloat(element.qty);
                });
              
                console.log('total qty', totalQTY)
      }
})
```