# ASP.NET MVC DataTable sum column

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am needing to sum the "Total" column. I would like to add the result to the footer of the table.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#orderTable").DataTable(
            {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Orders/GetList",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "CustomerName" },
                    { "data": "OrderDate" },
                    { "data": "Total" },
                ]
            });
    });
</script>
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else searching for a solution:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#orderTable").DataTable(
            {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Orders/GetList",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "CustomerName" },
                    { "data": "OrderDate" },
                    { "data": "Total" },
                ],

                 footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;
                    // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                    var intVal = function (i) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
                    };

                    // Total over this page
                    data = api.column(2, {
                        page: 'current'
                    }).data(); pageTotal = data.length ? data.reduce(function (a, b) { return intVal(a) + intVal(b); }) : 0;

                    // Update footer
                     $(api.column(2).footer()).html('$' + pageTotal);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

ref: [Jquery DataTable column Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438142/jquery-datatable-column-sum)
(Good structural reference in second answer)

ref: https://www.ihbc.org.uk/consultationsdb_new/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Answer (score 0):

There is option called `drawCallback`, use that  like below.

```
 drawCallback: function () {
        var yourSum = $('#orderTable').DataTable().column(number).data().sum(); // column number just like 1 , 2, 3, 4  ............... which you try to add 
        $('#total').html(sum); // #total is your html element id
      }
```

And HTML for total:

```
 <div id="total"></div>
```

Via CSS place your `div` where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think so best thing to do is getting sum directly from the server something like ("/Orders/GetTotal")
You can handle GetTotal And GetList together to prevent double request to database

Comment: @Foster90 As far as I remember kendo and Telerik grids use a similar solution. They get total value and table data from serverside from separated requests